# Xcode 10 is crashing when making connection of views to the controller

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

My Xcode has suddenly started crashing when I am trying to make storyboard connection to the view class. I am **control dragging** the view from storyboard to the view class and as soon as as the pointer gets to the class pane it crashes all of a sudden. I tried removing the derived data, restarting my mac but nothing helped. What can be the problem for this?

my Xcode version : Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)
my macos version : 10.14.4 (18E226)

here is the Gif of crashing

[image: XCode 10 Crash]

Comment: Can you work around it by dragging the other way? Can you work around it by using the Connections inspector instead of the code assistant?

Comment: @matt yeah I have tried that also. But its also crashing there also.

Comment: Well you didn’t show the crash log so it’s hard to guess what’s happening. Maybe your storyboard is hosed. I presume you don’t have this problem for a new project, so make a new project and migrate into it. And file a bug with Apple of course.

Comment: The crash log might get recorded at /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports. Please check if you can get any log information there. Post if you find one. Thanks!

Comment: @matt this is a big project. I highly doubt moving to new project will be an wise idea. I will look into the logs and post if any

Comment: Thanks for the location @VinayHosamane

Comment: "I highly doubt moving to new project will be an wise idea" Well continuing with _this_ project doesn't sound particularly wise either. Life is a trade-off. Another possibility of course would be to roll back to the first commit from before this issue arose, so that you can see how this mess got started. Git can help you locate that commit.

Comment: @matt how will I know if the storyboard is corrupted or not?

Comment: By whether you crash making this move.

Answer (score -1):

Classic Xcode! I must say

you can connect IBOutlets in many ways though. Secondary click on the Node App Cell view will show you the outlet connectors you can drag from that menu to the view itself.